# Запятая пропущена или не поставлена автором?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, порядок-слов

***При малейшем неверном шаге () пугаясь расстаться, они сосредоточенно искали линию равновесия, заводившую их порой на проезжую часть.***

В данном предложении неясен состав деепричастного оборота. Если обстоятельство входит в оборот, то порядок слов в нем будет нарушен, но чем это можно объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему нарушен? Автор выстроила предложение так, как хотела, логическое ударение падает на "расстаться". Иначе падало бы на "шаге": *Пугаясь расстаться при малейшем неверном шаге...* — и менялся бы смысл.
Сравните:
**При малейшем неверном шаге пугаясь расстаться...** = *совершая* шаг, они пугались, что он приведёт к расставанию.
**Пугаясь расстаться при малейшем неверном шаге...** = они боялись расстаться из-за малейшего неверного шага, то есть шаги эти *не* совершали.
**Пугаясь при малейшем неверном шаге расстаться** — этот вариант был бы пограничным между двумя вышеобъяснёнными, то есть его можно было бы прочитать и с одним смыслом, и с другим: **Пугаясь при малейшем неверном шаге // расстаться** (шаги совершались) либо **пугаясь // при малейшем неверном шаге расстаться** (шаги не совершались).

P. S. Добро пожаловать в высокую литературу :)

Comment: Но при обособлении  ударение тоже падает  на "расстаться". При малейшем неверном шАге, пугаясь расстАться, они...    Здесь же они тоже совершают шаг и потом пугаются. А вот измененный порядок слов затрудняет чтение, особенно если рассмотреть все ваши варианты, с ним лучше обращаться аккуратно. P. S. Высокая литература дается с трудом, как и всё высокое...

Comment: @Sharon не затрудняет) Когда пройдёт адаптация, вы это начнёте чувствовать (как и в случае с неклассическим оформлением прямой речи). // Здесь не нужна запятая, потому что здесь инверсия предложения *Пугаясь расстаться при малейшем неверном шаге...* Здесь же вы не станете ставить запятую?

Comment: Пугаясь расстаться при малейшем неверном шАге...Не буду ставить, но здесь ударение на "шаге", а нужно на "расстаться". Кстати, при обособлении "расстаться" подчеркивается, да и шаг они тоже совершают. Чем же нехорош стандартный вариант с обособлением?

Comment: @Sharon странный подход... Почему 'нехорош' и в какой момент времени инверсия перестала быть весьма распространённым и, стало быть, вполне стандартным тропом?.. Если я сегодня ел на обед суп, то это не значит, что каша хуже. Возможно, в книге где-то неподалёку встречается предложение с той же структурой и автор избежала таким образом повторения. Возможно, она сочла эту запятую лишней в плане влияния на темп и ритм текста. Возможно, это сделано специально для того, чтобы читатель зацепился глазом за конструкцию, тем самым автор регулирует скорость чтения.

Comment: @Sharon поясню про скорость: в фильме режиссёр способен диктовать свой событийный темп. Каждый элемент появится на экране на таком временнОм расстоянии от другого элемента, какое задумано. Писатель так чётко не может влиять на читателя, зато может косвенно, целым рядом приёмов. Возможно, вы удивитесь, но идеально гладкий текст — это плохо. По той же причине, по которой плоха идеально скользкая трасса.

Comment: @Sharon и ещё: в ушах всех филологов навязла фраза, что "Пушкин создал литературный русский язык". Но кто задумывается над ней? А ведь Пушкин действительно его создал — опираясь на тогдашние нормы, но меняя их, подправляя своим гением. Прочие великие авторы тоже работали с языком напрямую, правили его под свою эпоху. И это продолжается. Вы, наверное, привыкли, что сперва Розенталь, Кустова, Лопатин, а вся художка — под ними. Так вот нет. Языковая проза выше справочников. Как и раньше, лит. язык создаётся мастерами, а потом, если находки пройдут проверку временем, справочники их кодифицируют.

Comment: 1. Инверсия имеет определенный смысл, вот я и пытаюсь разобраться какой. Сейчас мне кажется, что она не захотела членить оборот на части, сохраняя при этом нужное ударение. Предложение распространенное, и важно было противопоставить цельный деепричастный оборот со значением цели следующей части предложения. 2. Скорость чтения там и так небольшая –  пара страниц за 10 минут :)  И она же пишет почти как Лев Толстой – одно предложение на полстраницы.

Comment: 3. Я всегда сочувствовала "художке" (кстати, как и Розенталь) и против излишнего формализма, но письменная речь должна быть нормированной, то есть подчиняться закону. Для "свободного письма" в правилах достаточно возможностей. Согласна, что практика речи влияет на правила, никто этого не отрицает. Но новые формы должны иметь достаточную частотность, чтобы они были внесены в правила.

Comment: @Sharon Лев Толстой, кстати, не относится к тем великим, которые создавали язык. Его величие проявлялось в других аспектах творчества, а вот язык у него довольно грузен, даже топорен, лишён изящества, изобретательности. Сравнить, к примеру, с Чеховым, чей стиль стал фактически эталоном для рассказов и до сих пор звучит современно. При этом масштаб таланта Чехова в других аспектах, ясно, уступает масштабу Толстого.

Comment: А мне как раз и не нравятся его длинные предложения. У нас темп жизни другой, это тоже надо учитывать. К примеру, начал читать предложение, а тут телефон звонит. Поговорил, начал его снова читать ...и т.д. :) Вот и давайте писать как Чехов.

Comment: @Sharon кратко, ёмко пишет Водолазкин, но вас же и он не радует :)

Comment: Пока радует, но я немного прочитала (может, потом еще разочарует). И прямая речь у него здесь  удачно оформлена, как ни странно. Надо только зафиксировать прием и ярлычок повесить  – когда такую форму можно применять.